# Writing Asian Language in WMS QGIS Server

Tags: qgis, wms, server

I have a WMS QGIS Server works perfectly, but it cannot present Asian Fonts (Hebrew). It writes a stranger characters (see picture below).

What can I do to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Which character encoding do you use?

Comment: Need to use UTF-8 but, no idea how to set it into a WMS server

Comment: In QGIS Server just set the datasource to utf8. Its within layerproperties.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but most of the time, this kind of issue is due to 2 possibles cases:

- you did not add the hebrew fonts (or do not have the same available fonts on the server) on the remote machine hosting QGIS Server
- you did not set explicitly the layers encoding as some source use the default system encoding when you open them (and they differ if on Linux on Windows). It's quite often, if you host on Linux server your QGIS Server while doing your projects on a Windows machine.